# PHP try / catch custom exception overriden by catch

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, overriding

Assuming the following code

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\TransferException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException;


try{
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/api', [
        'json' => [
            'method'    => 'xyz',
        ]
    ]);

    $rpcResult = json_decode($response->getBody());
    if(isset($rpcResult->error))
        throw new \App\Exceptions\APIExeption('error in sending api command ' . $rpcResult->error);

    return $rpcResult->result;
}

catch(ClientException | ServerException $e){

    throw new \App\Exceptions\APIExeption('error in sending api command ' . $e->getResponse()->getreasonPhrase() . " " . $e->getResponse()->getstatusCode());

}

catch(ConnectException $e){

    throw new \App\Exceptions\APIExeption('error in sending api command ' . $e->gethandlerContext()['error']);
}

//general
catch(\Exception $e){

    throw new \App\Exceptions\APIExeption('error in sending api command (general)');
}
```

Whenever the API itself returns an error, the following custom exception should be thrown:

```
throw new \App\Exceptions\APIExeption('error in sending api command ' . $rpcResult->error);
```

For some reason, whenever this exception is thrown, the **general** catch block is called too, meaning it somehow "overrides" my custom exception from above.

Any idea how I can prevent this?

Comment: It is probably because `APIExeption` extends `Exception`.  How to prevent this?  Don't use exceptions for your programs workflow.

Comment: Yes it extends the exception, but how to get this working inside my current programs flow?

Comment: Then dont catch exception.

Comment: Catch `\App\Exceptions\APIExeption` and do something with it, even if that means throwing it again via `throw $e` to break out of your try catch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bubble up your exception outside of your try catch block, put this first.

your exception throw is within the confines of your try catch block

```
catch( \App\Exceptions\APIExeption $e ){
    throw $e;
}
```

or remove your "general" catch statement